Does a Question with Poor-Quality Code Count as a Low-Quality Question?
Sometimes, users post code that is a bit messy and does not follow clean coding principles. Additionally, the code might include comments in a language other than English. However, this might be a personal choice regarding how they develop their programs.

Does this type of question, with poor-quality code or non-English comments, count as a low-quality question?
Is it wrong to answer such questions?

How should we deal with such questions? Should the code be improved by other users, or should it remain as it is?
like this post on stackoverflow
Window immediately closing

"Should the code be improved by other users, or should it remain as it is?". In questions, it should usually not be "improved" by other users, since the "improvements" could change the meaning of the question.

As long as I can read the code, and understand the code, poor quality code is fine.  If the comments are not in English that’s an entirely different problem. If you are asking a question on SO the MRE should be clear enough and question written in  English.

Well, for the Question (Qt) you've linked to as an example, the whole Qt is Low-Quality, not only the Code, ... and it should never have graduated from the 'Staging Ground': Title "not best", Code Block not formatted correctly (many useless empty lines), half of the Post and Code is in Russian, Code provided as a "Code Dump" (and not as a [mre]) because 'SO' = "Debugging Service", there is even some Copyright notice in the Code conflicting with the 'SO'-License, and the Tags were also not right... + Noise had to be removed...

The problem here has nothing to do with the quality of the code.

No, code quality has very little influence on question quality.
You can still write a good question about bad code. More often than not, the bad code is the reason a user needs to ask a question...
Even if the question's code and comments are written in a language other than English, that might not even influence how easy the question is to understand, or how answerable it is.
There's no "one size fits all" answer to this... Question quality should be judged on a case-by-case basis.
So, to answer your 2 points: It depends.

No, but bad code quality usually implies the question is of low quality too. You'll often see such questions with multiple downvotes. It's also possible that the issue stems from the bad code, in other words, if the code would be clean the user wouldn't ever run into such issue.
It's not wrong to answer such questions as long as you don't repeat the same issues in your answer. Either fix all issues or focus only on the core problem and ignore the rest of the bad code.

Should the code be improved by other users, or should it remain as it is?

That depends on what the issues with the code are. If it's just poor formating and dead code then by all means you can improve it and leave a comment for the OP to do the same in their codebase. By fixing the code in the question you are risking that you accidentally fix the main ask of the question. If you are an SME and you are trying to make the question easier to understand then there's no harm in removing irrelevant code or rewriting the MCVE completely. Most of the time it's not worth the effort editing the code in the question and it's better to just leave a comment pointing out the shortcomings.

"It's not wrong to answer such questions as long as you don't repeat the same issues in your answer." what do you mean "_don't repeat the same issues " if i shouldn't change the code as @yivi comments says " since the improvements could change the meaning of the question. _"

@mehdi You can and you should fix the code that you put in your answer. Just don't edit the question unless there's a good reason to do so.
